# Codeigniter custom language in input rules

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, message, rules

How can I insert a custom language in a `is_unique` rule?

This is my input rule:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'lang:user_email', 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]');
```

I tried this to insert a custom language:

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('is_unique', $this->lang->line('user_email_unique'));
```

and this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('is_unique', 'lang:user_email_unique');
```

But it's not working.

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to set it on the fly like this. Create a new language file for the validation rules and put the appropriate translation in there